# Notices, exceptions and debug message make build unstable while running Drupal tests on Jenkins

Tags: php, drupal, jenkins, automated-tests, drush

Jenkins runs Drupal tests (simpletest core module) of some custom modules. Tests pass, however  result considered unstable because of some warnings, notices, etc.

Same 'unstable' result is when some tests fails, so I couldn't run next job if build unstable.

Setting php error reporting and display errors doesn't help.

Using scripts/run-tests.sh. Drush test-run made build fail (even not unstable) because of some drush messages.

Any way to check if only real tests passed, not looking at other mesaages?

Comment: if your application is throwing warnings / notices and / or even exceptions. it sounds like it's not ready for deployment yet...

Comment: Unfortunately fixing all notices/warnings/exceptions is not an option right now

Comment: Looks like it is problem with JUnit which treats test fails and error similarly. Got some clues here https://pzolee.blogs.balabit.com/2012/11/jenkins-vs-junit-xml-format/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to fix all notices and warnings to resolve this issue.
Trouble was in missing some modules including while running tests on test installation profile